# python, indices of minima array

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, minimum, indices

I'm working with python 3 in Jupyter Notebook.

Imagine I have:

```
import numpy as np

q = np.array([5, 2, 6, 7, 2])
```

I now want to find the indices of the minima of the array; in this case the numbers 1 and 4.

I tried using:

```
np.argmin(q)
```

This gives:

```
1
```

Unfortunately np.argmin() only works when there is only one minimum. How do I find the index of the other minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where()`:

```
np.where(q == q.min())[0]
```

Result :

```
array([1, 4])
```